# How can I write a stored procedure to change the datatype of table under datadictionary to money from numeric type

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, advantage-database-server, data-dictionary, sap-data-dictionary

We convert DBF table to ADT. While running the code after conversion, an error pops up in numeric datatype in columns. If we manually change the datatype to money it will work. I want to automate this stored procedure to change the table column datatype and find out if there is `sp_ModifyFieldProperty` in procedure.

But nothing happened and got prompt with error in advantage data architect v.10

> poQuery: Error 7200: AQE Error: State=HY000; NativeError = 5254;
>   ...etc

Please help with any info on this topic

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_ModifyFieldProperty(
‘fdcku00’,
‘FDC_WID’, `money`,
‘FIELD_CAN_BE_NULL’,‘FALSE’,
‘RETURN_ERROR’,NULL );

Comment: Please post the *full* error message.

Comment: poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError = 5154;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] Error 5154:  Execution of the stored procedure failed.  Error 7200:  
AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2121;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Column not found: ‘fdcku00’ -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 43 (line: 2 
column: 1)

Comment: The error message is a bit odd, since you are passing 'fdcku00' as the table name to the stored procedure. Anyway ADS is complaining about the tablename and / or column name argument (the first two arguments). Check that you are actually passing the right table and column name to the SP.

Comment: Oh and you could also use the `ALTER TABLE … ALTER COLUMN` syntax as an alternative.

Comment: Syntax
sp_ModifyFieldProperty(
TableName,CHARACTER,200,
FieldName,CHARACTER,200,

Property,CHARACTER,200,
Value,MEMO,
ValidationOption,CHARACTER,25,
FailTable,CHARACTER,515 )

This was the code I followed from the web (http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.0/adssql/sp_modifyfieldproperty.htm) .The first parameter is TableName and second one is Column.

Comment: ok thank you @Jens Mühlenhoff Alter works as procedure. Thank you very much.